# how to change datagrid row background color with value taken from database in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I want to change datagrid row background color, by taking value from Database. 
I have 2 value "ERROR" and "OK". If Column string value is ERROR then row color will be red and if OK then It must be Green. This value get from database by executing query. I have these values in dataset. I am not clear that how to achieve this?

I have tried below code:

```
<Window x:Class="stackDatagridColor.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:stackDatagridColor"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <viewModels:viewmodel x:Key="viewmodel"/>
    <viewModels:BrushConverter x:Key="BrushConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource viewmodel}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="ERROR">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="OK">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class viewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<myItem> collection;
    public ObservableCollection<myItem> Collection
    {
        get { return collection; }
        set { collection = value; OnPropertyChanged("Collection"); }
    }


    public viewmodel()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<myItem>();
        myItem item1 = new myItem { Name = "name1", Status = "OK" };
        myItem item2 = new myItem { Name = "name2", Status = "ERROR" };
        DispatchService.Invoke(() =>
            {
                Collection.Add(item1);
            Collection.Add(item2);
            });
    }


    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Simple Class

```
public class myItem
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Dispatcher class

```
public static class DispatchService
{
    public static void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        Dispatcher dispatchObject = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
        if (dispatchObject == null || dispatchObject.CheckAccess())
        {
            action();
        }
        else
        {
            dispatchObject.Invoke(action);
        }
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
public class BrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string input = value as string;
        switch (input)
        {
            case "ERROR":
                return Brushes.Red;
            case "OK":
                return Brushes.Green;
            default:
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

I just want to bind dataset column to trigger. If trigger get ERROR string then background row color change to red and vice versa.

Comment: Your code seems to work. I'm not sure if I understand where you have a problem.

Comment: I did not get that how to bind dataset to viewmodel

Comment: Is a dataset an instance of System.Data.DataSet class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly `Collection` property should be declared in this way:

```
public DataSet Collection { ... }
```

`ItemSource` binding in XAML should be also changed:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection.Tables[Table1], Mode=OneWay,...
```

In the code above *Table1* is a name of a table within a dataset you want to bind to. To test this code create a simple dataset in this way:

```
 public viewmodel()
 {
        var tb = new DataTable("Table1");
        tb.Columns.Add("Status");
        tb.Columns.Add("Name");

        tb.Rows.Add("OK", "name1");
        tb.Rows.Add("ERROR", "name2");
        tb.Rows.Add("ERROR", "name3");

        Collection2 = new DataSet();
        Collection2.Tables.Add(tb);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I got My answer...No neew of such stuffs..Just used loadingrow event. This is very much usefull.
See Below

```
DataGridRow row = e.Row;
DataRowView rView = row.Item as DataRowView
if(rView != null && rView.Row.ItemArray[4].ToString().Contains("ERROR")) 
{
  e.row.Background= new SolidColorBrush(Color.Red);
}
else
{
 e.row.Background= new SolidColorBrush(Color.Green);
}
```

Comment: what is "e" in this case?

Comment: @ajivani 'LoadingRow' is the event of DataGrid. Dipika is writing the above code in that event, if I am not mistaken.